# Spring MVC, Spring Data JPA, Spring Security integration

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-security

I have a Spring MVC web app which uses JPA and Hibernate to map objects to a MySQL database. I have added Spring Security and have it working so far as using an in memory model. I want to add user and role entities to integrate with Spring Security.

I was wondering if someone could point me in the direction of how to do this or any tutorials on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement an [UserDetailsService](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#userdetailsservice-implementations) which loads your User- and Rolemodel. Its just the loadUserByUsername which will return a [UserDetails](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html) Object. The UserDetails itself will have a list of all roles. A role is here called know as GrantedAuthority. Theres a SimpleGrantedAuthority to create it from a simple Rolename (String).

But maybe [JdbcDaoImpl](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/JdbcDaoImpl.html) is enough for your needs.

Update due question in comment:

Just design your User Role relation as you would normally do. In your UserDetails Implementation you need to return your roles in getAuthorities as GrantedAuthority.

Example:
reduced to the minimum.

Role

```
@Entity(name = "auth_role")
public class Role {

  @Id
  @Column
  private String id;

  @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
  /**
   *unique and transformed to GrantedAuthority,can be used in Spring expression hasRole, etc
  **/
  private String name;


  @Column(nullable = true)
  private String description;
}
```

User

```
@Entity(name = "auth_user")
public class User implements UserDetails {

   @Id
   @Column
   private String id;

   @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
   private String name;


   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
   /** 
    * relation to our roles
   **/
   private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();

   /**
   * implements getAuthorities and transformes our Roles using the unique names to 
   * SimpleGrantedAuthority
   **/
   public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
     Set<GrantedAuthority> authList = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

     for (Role role : user.getRoles()) {
       authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
     }        

     // Return list of granted authorities
     return authList;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go. I want to map other entities to my user entity so I'll probably need to use the first method.

Comment: If it solved your question, you could accept my answer. Or help me to improve it. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, would it be possible for you to provide me with a code sample or point me in the direction of one.

Comment: I've implemented UserDetailsService and created a User entity which extends UserDetails. How can I add a role to my User entity?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I had actually already got this working, I'll accept your answer.